# How to remove a Merge commit from Git history without losing subsequent commits

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request, git-rebase

I have a Git repository "B" with branch `clean` which is a fork of another Git repository "A" with branch `main`.

My B repository commit history includes a merge commit from the upstream repository A, which I want to remove.

Here's my commit history now:

```
ce8f54a (HEAD -> clean, origin/clean): New update 4 
ef31ae4: New update 3 
a8171b9: Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main' into clean
b65a7cd (upstream/main): solution of c++ exercise (from fork)
33d8267: new c++ exercise (from fork)
ac8106a: New update 2
d86297f: New update 1
83c73b2: solution of java exercise (from fork)
7629f4b: new java exercise (from fork)
```

Initially, I removed the intermediate "Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream/main' into clean" commit that came after commit `83c73b2` using `git rebase`, and it worked well. But now, if I run the same command again, it removes all my pushed commits and aligns my repository "B" with the upstream "A".

Running the interactive `git rebase -i HEAD~6` for removing the merge doesn't work because the its commit won't show up. Simply resetting to the commit before the merge (`b65a7cd`) will have the same behaviour as `git rebase`. It also remove all my pushed commits, as the SHA is the same for the upstream. Namely, it resets my "B" history to match "A".

How can I remove the merge commit from my Git history without losing my pushed commits?

I need to do this multiple times, so that in the end I can push a clean Pull Request which has just the "updates" commit and not the "Merge etc." ones as well.

Comment: If the merge commit is an ancestor of your pushed commits it's impossible to remove it while keeping your pushed commits.

Answer (score 1):

`git revert a8171b9` will let you undo the changes in the merge but keep subsequent commits there.  If there are conflicts you'll need to sort those out before you'll be able to complete the revert.  git will show you which files have a conflict during the revert.

Comment: This will not work. I don't want to revert the commit, I just want to hide it from the history. If I revert the commit, it will create a new "Revert x" commit which will also show up in the final Pull Request I want to make. My PR needs to just have the ```ce8f54a - ef31ae4 - ac8106a - d86297f``` commits.

Comment: Ok, just fyi hiding commits from history isn't really a thing for git and is not a good practice for source control.  You can undo the changes but the whole point of source control is to track the changes so hiding them isn't really a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I am finding it difficult to understand your question, however worst case you can always create a fresh branch off of a historic commit.

```
git checkout -b new_branch some_commit
```

Then cherry-pick whichever commits you want onto that branch and you can add multiple commits to the same cherry-pick command, if you find that easier:

```
get cherry-pick commit1 commit2 commit3 ...
```

TL;DR - On a fresh branch you can build any sequence of commits you want, then push that new branch to the remote.